# How do i make a <option> for every child in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do i make a `<option>` for every child in an array? Here is my array:

```js
//select ref
const gebruikersref = firebase.database().ref('Gebruikers/')
        gebruikersref.once('value', function(snapshot){
        // get the number of childs
            var childlength = snapshot.numChildren()

            for(let i=0; i<childlength;i++) {
                //make all the <option>`s for every child in the array
            }
                
        }); 

});
```

This is what i tried:

```js
//This returns all the users but x times the users inside the array because it is nested in a foreach loop
const gebruikersref = firebase.database().ref('Gebruikers/')
        self = this
        gebruikersref.once('value', function(snapshot){
            var email = self.email
            var voornaam = ''
            var achternaam = ''
            var lidnummer = ''
            var medespelers = ''
            var voornamen = ''
            var lidnummers = ''
            var childlength = snapshot.numChildren()
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                const data = childSnapshot.exportVal();
                self.voornamen = data.Voornaam
                self.lidnummers = data.Lidnummer
                for(let i=0; i<childlength;i++) {
                    self.medespelers = "<option value='speler"+i+"'>" + self.voornamen + " - " + self.lidnummers + " </option>"
                    console.log(self.medespelers)
                }
                if(data.Email == email) {
                    self.voornaam = data.Voornaam;
                    self.achternaam = data.Achternaam;
                    self.lidnummer = data.Lidnummer;
                }
                
                
            }); 

        });
```

```js
//this only returns the last player because the foreach loop runs and sets the names and then the for loop runs ans returns only the last user x the users in the array
const gebruikersref = firebase.database().ref('Gebruikers/')
        self = this
        gebruikersref.once('value', function(snapshot){
            var email = self.email
            var voornaam = ''
            var achternaam = ''
            var lidnummer = ''
            var medespelers = ''
            var voornamen = ''
            var lidnummers = ''
            var childlength = snapshot.numChildren()
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                const data = childSnapshot.exportVal();
                self.voornamen = data.Voornaam
                self.lidnummers = data.Lidnummer
                if(data.Email == email) {
                    self.voornaam = data.Voornaam;
                    self.achternaam = data.Achternaam;
                    self.lidnummer = data.Lidnummer;
                }
                
                
            }); 
            for(let i=0; i<childlength;i++) {
                self.medespelers = "<option value='speler"+i+"'>" + self.voornamen + " - " + self.lidnummers + " </option>"
                console.log(self.medespelers)
            }

        });
```

Comment: You  can just write the HTML as a string and (presumably) then store it to output later. Or have you got a more specific issue than that?

Comment: Thanks for the update... `self.medespelers = ` will overwrite the medespelers variable every time the loop runs, rather than adding to it. So you'll only end up with the last one in that variable. Perhaps you need += instead, so it concatenates the string. But then you'll have lots of options with the same data in them, since the other fields aren't changing. More likely, the code to generate the option needs to be inside your forEach loop - it's not clear why you've got two separate loops here.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson yes that is the problem i did not know why i used 2 loops while i could just do: ```medespelers.push(self.voornamen + " - " + self.lidnummers);``` in the foreach loop and then make the ```var medespelers``` an array and set ```self.medespelers``` to ```medespelers``` outside the loop.